# How to interpret KVM emulation error

Tags: qemu, kvm, xen

I am running qemu and I find that I have an emulation error which only occurs when I run using KVM. Running without KVM I do not see this error. I have tried different CPUs for qemu as the exception in the kernel indicates that it is an instruction decoding error but this doens't help. What does this error mean and what do I need to debug it (eg. symbols and vm mappings in the guest).

```
KVM internal error. Suberror: 1
emulation failure
RAX=0000000000000001 RBX=ffff8b00f1820b10 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=0000000000000001
RSI=0000000000000001 RDI=ffff8b00f18a15ba RBP=ffffe58890ee94d0 RSP=ffff8b00f1820a10
R8 =0000000000000002 R9 =fffff80a939b2048 R10=fffff80a93b66380 R11=fffff80a933e0000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000002 R14=ffffe5888ef217b8 R15=ffffe5888ef21403
RIP=fffff80a935f0031 RFL=00010293 [--S-A-C] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00209b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0018 0000000000000000 00000000 00409300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
FS =0053 00000000a5c9e000 00003c00 0040f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
GS =002b fffff8018c9c0000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c00000
TR =0040 fffff8018e44e070 00000067 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     fffff8018e44d000 0000006f
IDT=     fffff8018e44d070 00000fff
CR0=80050033 CR2=ffffa80413ca5000 CR3=0000000108a69000 CR4=001506f8
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000d01
Code=ff 0b 75 10 f7 85 64 02 00 00 00 00 02 00 0f 84 e9 04 00 00 <0f> 10 07 0f b6 c1 48 6b c8 26 0f 11 44 19 01 0f 10 4f 10 0f 11 4c 19 11 8b 47 20 89 44 19
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tracing you need to enable kernel tracing and forward this to the list for assistance.